# VB Console Application, no tasks auto-close

Tags: vb.net, console, task

my fellow community members!
I'm creating my own Command Prompt and I want to know something about it.
When my program is out of a task, for example this code:

```
        ElseIf cmdStr = "version" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        Console.Write("Current version: ")
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
        Console.Write(appVersion)
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
        Console.ReadLine()
```

After `Console.Readline()` there is empty space.
The console application will shutdown.
Is there anyway to let it do a task if there is no task?
I always put this in those empt spots:

```
Console.Clear
Main()
```

But I'm tired of doing that since i have almost reached 50 commands.
Is there a way? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could direct it to another sub?

Comment: Put it all in an infinite `While`-loop? When you want to stop the tasks just call `Exit While` and it should continue with the lines after the loop (if any).

Comment: I don't think that this will work but have you tried `console.readkey` ?

Comment: And if you find the command with `If....ElseIf....ElseIf....End If` Try this: http://pastebin.com/raw/6sqJ7hfi. It will save you some time.

Comment: Eh, I think you guys don't understand me. It shouldn't loop a command. If the command or something else (like a bug) ends and it has no tasks. The application closes. I want it to just go to the Main() method. Which is what i sayd. 'Console.Clear' & 'Main()'. I want to do it for if it does not have ANY task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are finding you are rewriting a lot of code for the commands look at refactoring them. You mention you are tired of calling clear and back into the main sub, but if this is common between all of your commands then you could do something like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class ConsoleCommand
    MustOverride Sub command
    Public sub run()
        command()
        Console.ReadLine()
        Main()
    End sub
End Class

Public Class VersionCommand
    Inherits ConsoleCommand
    Public Overrides Sub command()
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        Console.Write("Current version: ")
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
        Console.Write(appVersion)
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class CommandFactory
    Public Function GetCommand(cmdStr As string) As ConsoleCommand
        Select Case cmdStr
            Case "version"
                Return New VersionCommand
            Case Else
                Return nothing
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

then in your main sub:

```
sub Main()

dim factory as new CommandFactory()
dim cmdText as string = Console.ReadLine()
dim command = factory.GetCommand(cmdText)
command.run()

end sub
```

Alternatively remove the

```
Console.ReadLine()
Console.Clear
Main()
```

from each if/else branch and place it after the End If

//In response to original posters comment around wanting to exit on "Close"

```
Sub Main()

dim cmdStr as string = String.Empty
do until cmdStr = "Close"
cmdStr = Console.ReadLine()
'Your if block goes here, minus the call back into main - which is now looping
loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, for your time and effort. But this doesn't solve my problem. I still need to enter everything in the Case section. This has 2 bad sides. 1: My code gets longer. 2: I could just do 'Main()' like I do now.

Comment: If you are making a calls to Console.ReadLine(),  Console.Clear + Main() in every if/else branch then refactoring in this manner will save you quite a bit of code, means you adhere to the DRY principle and has a benefit that your main sub will only contain a few lines of code

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I do not want to do that as (a modder) I experienced alot of bugs with that. I want to know how to not let the application close, only with the command 'Close' and the exit button.

Comment: Okay, one question remaining. Where do i put the `Do Until cmdStr = "Close"` ??  I have a welcome message. Do i need to put my welcome message above the `Do Until` or below?

Comment: Purely personal preference, if you want your welcome message to repeat after each command is finished then put it directly below the do until statement. If you only want the welcome message to appear when the program is first started put it above the do until statement.